# What is a better way of reading a file in c++?

Tags: c++

I want to read a file in c++. I want to know which is a better way of reading (speed and elegance).

I am a bit confused with reading a file character by character or reading string by string.

I just want to have my own xml/html parser. And I want to parse even an unformatted xml/html file. So which method would be more suited for my purpose?

Comment: Neither: You want to read tokens ([lexems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexeme)). In XML a lexeme is either a tag or a block of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either can work perfectly well. The real question is what you want to do with the data after you read it -- if your processing is oriented toward complete lines, then read complete lines. If it's oriented toward words, then read words. If it's oriented toward characters, then read single characters.

Just for example, if you wanted to read a file and capitalize every letter it contained, it would probably be easiest to read a character at a time, capitalize it, write it out, and repeat.

If you wanted to capitalize the initial letter in ever word in the file, it would probably be easiest to read a word, capitalize the first letter, write out the word, and repeat.

Neither is really better, worse, more elegant, etc., than the other -- it's purely a question of choosing what suits what you're trying to do. One might be marginally faster than the other, but that'll depend heavily on the standard library you're using, and there's little (if any) way to predict which will be faster in general.

Comment: hi jerry I have updated my question can you provide your input on that?

Comment: At least for most parsing, you start with a lexer that reads characters and produces tokens, then in the next layer something that reads and processes the tokens. I'm not *sure* that's necessary to parse XML, but it would be my first choice. In theory HTML is similar, but in reality it's brutally ugly. I'd avoid it if humanly possible.